# .htaccess url rewriting /project/Login to /project/public/index.php/Login without redirecting URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this .htaccess code that works perfectly:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css)$ public/index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

...but this code redirects to public sub directory. I don't know if it's possible to rewrite url without redirecting, just use `/project/Login` appointing to `/project/public/index.php/Login`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteRule project/Login$ project/public/Login [L]

Have you tired something like that?  Your second link doesn't seem right "/project/public/index.php/Login", you shouldn't specify 'index.php' followed by another folder unless you have a RewriteRule that can handle it, otherwise the page doesn't exist on your server.

'**/project/public/index.php?Login**' (same as '/project/public/?Login') would be valid though, having the query string accessible as **$_GET['Login']**.

Hope this helps.